# Unable to generate signed apk using proguard

Tags: android, proguard, aar, buildconfig

I have generated two libraries(aar) with same package name as they are in different flavors. Now i'm integrating both into one another application, as both aar files have same packagename buildConfig.class got conflict. 
I fixed this by given multidexEnable = true in applications build.gradle.
But when i'm trying to generate signedApk with proguard file, Android studio throwing duplicate entry for buildConfig.class.
Any one knows about this?

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem with the proguard configuration.check all the libs which you added and make the necessary rules for each in the proguard.
you can try again after the clean project and buid again .if its not worked check the progrud rules again .you will get the idea from your logs .
Check this link which is a sample configuration : https://gist.github.com/albinmathew/c4436f8371c9c41461ab

Comment: I just added two libraries which i generated with same packagename.
Unable to fix with what you said. :(

Comment: Is there any way we could find the logs of which all libraries and codes are failing in the build process?

Comment: you can see that from gradle- build section in Android studio